# Multiple ajax request server response become 403 forbidden, Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-status-code-403, pos

I built a pos application in Laravel and hosted it on a shared hosting server. on the live server when I try to send ajax request multiple times to add products from the right side pane(by clicking image one after one) it starts responding 403 forbidden after some request.

[image]

Any help, what I can do to prevent this, and what is the cause?

Comment: Compare the last successful request request with the first failed one. Check if the `Set-Cookie` value is set in both and the session cookie has the same value.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use shared hosting server for live server. It has many restrictions

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the 403 is that laravel reject request if default request limit is reached out of limit. You can set the number of requests per min as per your project in app/Http/Kernel.php.

```
 'api' => [
            'throttle:150,1', // 150 requests per min
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Throttling would result in a 429 result code. 403 means unauthorised

Comment: I am using web guard, will be same for web guard too?

Comment: i checked using throttle, but it is different. throttle limit reaches it throws 429 as @apokryfos said. but on server i am getting 403. localhost everything is fine.